# Unable to create layer for WebView with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-nestedscrollview

I'm adding to NestedscrollView to a webview to can hide/show the toolbar when user do a scroll. The activity is working fine until I added the NestedScrollView to can do the hide/show movement. In this moment, I'm getting an error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for WebView, size 720x12996 exceeds max size 8192
```

This is my xml

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ly_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:background="@color/negro">
            </RelativeLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/generic_toolbar_browser" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/webview_browser"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_web_items"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_standard"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Generic_toolbar_browser

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/home_appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_browser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:background="@color/blanco">

        .....

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: The problem was in this line in my activity. After removed, all work fine webview_browser.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)

Comment: I am also getting the same error, In my case there is `WebView` in `ScrollView` and I want to stop scrolling of `WebView` so I am using this `android:scrollbars="none"` in WebView. **Is it going to work for me or Not**?
           Please Help

Answer (score 0):

A `WebView` can scroll by itself. It should not be necessary to place it inside a `NestedScrollView`. Doing that, will likely reduce the size of the WebView. Don't worry about the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`, it should work on `WebView`'s as well (all though there are edge cases that can be difficult to setup). E.g.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview_browser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_web_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_standard"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

If that does not work, have a look at the WebView's parents. One of them is probably too large (=it's height). So try to not go beyond the height of the screen

Comment: Yep, know is not crashing but is not doing the hide/show of toolbar. Is doing nothing.I've update my question with the toolbar code